# How to proceed the code to final decision in real time?

Tags: c++, opencv

I had develop the code. The problem is when I convert it into real time, it do not proceed to the final solution. What should I add to made the code proceed to the final solution? I want it read the code and give the result in frame by frame for only 30 seconds only, then it will proceed to the final decision. May anyone help me?

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    Mat frame,resize_blur_Img,fgmaskMOG,binaryImg;
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor>pMOG;
    pMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
    int frame_count=0;
    int detected_face_count = 0;
    int detected_motion_count = 0;
    CascadeClassifier cascade;
    if (!cascade.load("C:/opencv2410/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"))
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 7), Point(3, 3));

    while (true)
    {
        //MOTION DETECTION
        if (!(capture.read(frame)))
            break;
        frame_count++;
        resize(frame, resize_blur_Img, Size(frame.size().width, frame.size().height));
        pMOG->operator()(resize_blur_Img, fgmaskMOG, -1);
        threshold(binaryImg, binaryImg, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        int TotalNumberOfPixels = fgmaskMOG.rows*fgmaskMOG.cols;

        //FACE DETECTION
        capture >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        imshow("original", frame);
        vector<Rect>faces;
        cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, faces, 1.1, 4, 0, Size(40, 50));//(const Mat& image, vector <Rect>& objects, double scaleFactor, int minNeighbors,int flags, Size minSize,Size maxSize)

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            rectangle(frame, faces[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        }

        imshow("MOTION DETECTION", fgmaskMOG);
        imshow("FACE DETECTION", frame);
        char c = waitKey(10);

        printf("count of pixels: %d \n", countNonZero(fgmaskMOG));
        printf("%d Face Found !\n", faces.size());

        if (faces.size()>0 &&countNonZero(fgmaskMOG)>1)
        {
            detected_face_count++;
            detected_motion_count++;
            printf("FACE AND MOTION DETECTED !\n\n");
        }
        else if (faces.size()>0 && countNonZero(fgmaskMOG)==0)
        {
            detected_face_count++;
            printf("ONLY FACE DETECTED !\n\n");
        }
        else if (faces.size() == 0 && countNonZero(fgmaskMOG) > 1)
        {
            detected_motion_count++;
            printf("ONLY MOTION DETECTED !\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NOTHING DETECTED !\n\n");
        }

//I want it to stop until here after 30 second and show the final decision according to rule below

    }

    printf("count of frames: %d \n", frame_count);
    printf("count of frames has detected face: %d \n", detected_face_count);
    printf("count of motion detected: %d \n", detected_motion_count);
    printf("Face Found %d percent of frames ! \n", (int)(100 * detected_face_count / frame_count));
    printf("Motion Found %d percent of frames ! \n", (int)(100 * detected_motion_count / frame_count));

    //FINAL DECISION FROM ALL THE FRAME
    if (((float)(detected_face_count / frame_count) > 0.49) && (((float)detected_motion_count / (float)frame_count)>0.19))
    {
        printf("HUMAN DETECTED FROM BOTH DETECTION ! \n\n");
    }
    else if (((float)detected_motion_count / (float)frame_count)>0.19)
    {
        printf("POSSIBLE HUMAN DETECTED FROM MOTION DETECTION ONLY !\n\n");
    }
    else if ((float)(detected_face_count / frame_count) > 0.49)
    {
        printf("POSSIBLE HUMAN DETECTED FROM FACE DETECTION ONLY !\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("HUMAN NOT DETECTED \n\n");
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'making it real time'? Getting the video from a live cam instead of a recorded video? Can you post a minimal example of your code?

Comment: I had edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to incorporate boost, there's an accurate, platform independent way to do this:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
namespace posixtime = boost::posix_time;
...
posixtime::ptime startTime = posixtime::microsec_clock::local_time();
while ((posixtime::microsec_clock::local_time() - start).total_seconds() < 30)
{
    ...
```

See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) for details.  Of course, there are countless ways to do this, but I find this convenient.

Comment: Can it be more simple code? I can't run the code because I don't have the path of file.

Comment: if you have C++11 you should have the <chrono> library with the same features